# Query Creation - Do I use SUM, Group etc.?

Tags: mysql

I'm confused on how I could create the query in relation to counting rows.

Here is what my data looks like in the DB:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgeAV.png

I would like it to give me a total for each username where item = 1 and size = 3.

How would I do that? I've tried:

```
SELECT Username, SUM(size=3 AND item=1) as LargePopcornTotal FROM statistics2 GROUP BY Username;
```

I've tried IF statements with SUM and without SUM etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right lines, but you should limit in the WHERE clause, not in the sum. The sum is just used to "add" the results from all the grouped rows together.

```
SELECT
    username,
    SUM(quantity) as LargePopcornTotal
FROM
    statistics2
WHERE
    size = 3
    AND item = 1
GROUP BY
    username
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem with that is, I have other selects in that query which don't use the same WHERE.

Comment: Other selects in that query? Can you give some more detail of your "overall" query, then, as it sounds like your problem is larger than that which you describe in this question :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Mz5erRtc

You see how line 3-6 has a new select, or grabs a new line of data. I need to inset the query which I've spoke above, just in that query, so I cannot use WHERE as not all of the other data matches the WHERE in which the data above uses.

Comment: Okay, well your immediate problem is really that your table is not relational enough - you need to split your "items" (where an item would be LargePopcorn, SmallPopcorn etc, not just Popcorn) into a separate table. You should probably also split User's out into a separate table, too. You could do it with your table, but it will get very messy with sub-queries or joining the table against itself.

Comment: I did have it like that before.

http://puu.sh/cfHOb/0e41b893e4.png

But I was told to do the structure like this as it'd make it easier for me to perform queries. As the old way would have hundreds of sub queries just for one piece of data. So I've made it easier so it can just count the sizes instead of having to specify field names etc.

Comment: The old way was wrong too :) - "LargePopcorn" etc should be a VALUE in a column not a column name. Although if you want to do it properly properly, you'd have Item (eg popcorn), Size (eg large) and ItemVariant (which just links to the ID of Item and Size). I'm at work at the moment, but if nobody replies to this before this evening I'll try to give you an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Username, sum(quantity) as LargePopcornTotal
from statistics2
where item = 1
and size =  3
group by username
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select count(*) from stats where item = 1 and size = 3
```